# Formatação de Bloco de Texto em Latex

Tags: formatação, latex

Boa tarde! Estou tentando, sem sucesso, colocar esse bloco de texto nessa formatação da foto:

[image: Figura 01. Formatação desejada.]

Como faço isso em Latex?

Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

PS.: Estou usando o TeXstudio para editar.

Comment: Você está usando algum pacote de configuração? Não sou um grande utilizador de Latex, então é difícil eu dar uma resposta, mas quando crio documento em Latex eu uso uma suíte de arquivos que já deixa tudo configurado de acordo com as normas ABNT. Caso seja essa sua intenção, acho que pode procurar por abntex.

Comment: Não estou. O artigo tem que seguir o padrão da universidade. Um ou outro elemento usa a ABNT, e é até tranquilo configurar. O problema é esse alinhamento que tá me dando nos nervos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deve haver uma maneira inteligente de se fazer isso, mas a solução que encontrei serviu para meu propósito.
Este é o produto que cheguei:

```
\begin{flushleft}
\hspace*{<distância desejada, com a unidade definida ex: 8cm}
texto texto texto texto texto\\
\hspace*{<distância>}
texto texto texto texto texto\\
\hspace*{<distância>}
texto texto texto texto texto\\
\end{flushleft}
```

Aberto para soluções mais inteligentes.

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução mais consistente seria:

```
\thispagestyle{empty} % Numeração não deve aparecer na página de rosto.

\begin{center}
\textbf{\large TÍTULO:SUBTÍTULO}
\end{center}
\par
\vspace{7em}

\hspace*{8cm}\parbox{8.5cm}{{Artigo apresentado ao curso de graduação em ... da Universidade ... como requisito parcial para obtenção do título de ... em .... % ajuste a largura do \parbox de acordo com o tamanho de sua margem
\\[1em]
Orientador: x.
\\[1em]
Co-orientador: x }}

\par
\vspace{13em}
\begin{center}
\textbf{\large Brasília}\\
\textbf{\large Ano}
\end{center}
```